# TypeScript declaration merging for nested namespaces

Tags: typescript

There is an external module declaration with the shape:

```
declare module "external-module" {
  namespace SomeNS {
    namespace SubNS {
      // some functions.
      function someFunc(): void;
    }
  }
  exports = SomeNS;
}
```

I can some functions as `SomeNS.subNS.someFunc()`. But now I have found one method, `function methodMissingDefinition() {}`, missing its definition, and I want to fix it right in my code without modifying the third-party declaration.

Is there any tricks that allow me to do this?

Or it is impossible to do this and the only way is to urge the author to fix the declaration?

Answer (score 0):

So, *yes*, you should open a PR and encourage the third party maintainer to update the typings; in the meantime however I believe you can extend the third party typings like so:

```
import * as externalModule from 'external-module';

declare module 'external-module' {
  namespace SomeNS {
    namespace SubNS {
      // missing functions.
      function methodMissingDefinition(): void;
    }
  }
  exports = SomeNS;
}
```

and then import it like so:

```
import * as externalModule from 'external-module';
import 'myExternalModuleExtension';

externalModule.SubNS.methodMissingDefinition()
```

I'm extrapolating from this GitHub issue for reference: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10859